# Как задать масштабирование изображения для фона окна?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в *PyQt* возможно реализовать масштабирование изображения фона?

В настоящий момент я использую таблицу стилей `CSS`, но при попытке указать метод `background-size: cover/auto` терминал выдаёт сообщение:

> Unknown property background-size

Я знаю что в *PyQt* есть инструмент `QPalette`, но пока им не пользовался. 
Какой инструмент (`CSS` или `QPalette`) более гибкий и  производительней для оформления приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):   
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget) 


qss = """
#widget {
    border-image: url(boy.jpg) 0 0 0 0  ;           /* <---------- */
}
"""     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(950, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**boy.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает как нужно!

Comment: @Rett_oo пожалуйста.